# Issues with using Select2 to jump to page anchors

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a long page organized by state. I have a Select2 element at the top of the page that I would like to use to let visitors select a state and jump to that state further down the page via an anchor.

I’ll post my code in a bit, but let me first describe the issue. My solution works in most browsers, but I’ve discovered that it fails in IE11 and Edge. In those browsers, I see the desired content location flicker briefly into view before the page gets pulled back to having the Select2 element at the top of the page. It’s like Select2 really wants to be in view.

Here is my (simplified) code:

**HTML**

```
<select class="jumpmenu">
    <option value="">Jump to a State</option>
    <option value="#alabama">Alabama</option>
    <option value="#alaska">Alaska</option>
    [ ... ]
</select>

<a name="alabama" id="alabama">&nbsp;</a>
<h2>Alabama</h2>
<a name="alaska" id="alaska">&nbsp;</a>
<h2>Alaska</h2>
[ ... ]
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".jumpmenu").select2();

$('.jumpmenu').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
});
```

Is there a better way for me to construct this jump menu so that it will jump properly in IE and Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got [a few suggestions](https://forums.select2.org/t/issues-with-using-select2-to-jump-to-page-anchors/204/2) from John30013 on the Select2 forums, and one of them worked well for me. I ended up setting a short setTimeout, which allowed the select to close before jumping to the anchor. Here's the code that worked for me:

```
$('.jumpmenu').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    newHash = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location.hash = newHash;},100);
});
```